# Meaning of "somewhere between reading and slough"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> When the baby looked up at me from its wicker basket and winked *on the opposite seat somewhere between reading and slough* I became uneasy.

I don't know what the meaning of "somewhere between reading and slough" is.

Comment: I don't think babies *can* "wink", but your problem is that you haven't realised Reading and Slough are *places* on the train line.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about confusing place names with standard English words

Comment: The modifier _on the opposite seat_ is misplaced. 'When, somewhere between Reading and Slough, the baby looked up and winked at me from its wicker basket on the opposite seat, I became uneasy.'

Comment: Please be specific in your question titles. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Reading and Slough are both towns in Southern England on the same rail line out of London. Hence something happened, presumably on a train, somewhere between Reading and Slough.  Reading is pronounced 'Redding' when it means the town, not as 'reading'. Slough is pronounced to rhyme with 'cow', NOT as 'Sluff'.

Comment: I think you should say *Slough* rhymes with *cow*. I don't know how to pronounce *sloue*; to me it looks too much like the American pronunciation of *slough* as *sloo*.

Comment: Slough  (sloo, slou)  
A borough of southeast England, a residential and industrial suburb of London. Population: 126,000.;  
slough 1  (sluf, slou) also slew (sloo)  
n.  
1. A depression or hollow, usually filled with deep mud or mire.  
2. also slue A stagnant swamp, marsh, bog, or pond, especially as part of a bayou, inlet, or backwater.  
3. A state of deep despair or moral degradation.

Comment: @Peter Shor Quite right. It rhymes with cow.